# xpath and cssSelector for Selenium WebDriver or Selenium RC

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Publish" class="button submit">
```

I have written xpath as below:

```
//input[@value='Publish']
//input[@class='button submit']
//input[@type='submit']
```

What is the corresponding cssSelector for the above xpath for using in Selenium RC or WebDriver test?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>          xpath                           cssSelector
> //input[@value='Publish']            input[value=Publish]
> //input[@class='button submit']      input.button.submit
> //input[@type='submit']              input[type=submit]
> ```

Comment: You don't seem to have formatted that properly. Are you trying to make a table?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make a table by using excel. But unfortunately it broke down after copy paste here

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: Thanks for editing and make a well formatted table

Comment: Which one is the faster to use? either xpath or cssSelector?

Answer (score 1):

in order to select your input element you have to write somthing like this

```
input[type=submit] {
    color: red;
}
```

the syntax is quite similar to xpath

`input[att=val]` - Match when the element's "att" attribute value is exactly "val"